# Elements in stack view not shifting/adjusting

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have 4 buttons in a horizontal stack view with "Fill Equally" distribution. In one of the conditions I hide first button in stack view before the stack view is displayed, but the other 3 buttons stays in place (i.e. first button still holds the space) instead of moving and spacing out equally.

***Below is the details on my stack view:***

[image]
[image]

How can I adjust/spread the 3 buttons in the stack view when one button is hidden?

***Code to hide the button:***

```
    self.button1.alpha = 0.0
    self.button1.alpha = 0.0
    self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: self.button1.alpha this is just set the opacity of the button but it still there. use isHidden property

Comment: I had tried isHidden initially and with that as well I was getting the same result. I also tried having both i.e. isHidden and alpha, but button still holds up the space in the stack view.

Comment: Try to set leading constraint >=

Comment: Tried both >= and <=, nothing changed

Comment: You need to set isHidden = false like @RajaKishan suggested. How/where are you setting this? Are you sure the code is being called? Also, you don't need to call layoutIfNeeded

Answer (score 1):

setting the `alpha` value will not hide the view, it will reduce the opacity of the view, in your case `button1`. To spread the buttons evenly across the frame of the `UIStackView` when `button1` is hidden, you will have to hide `button1`. you can toggle the `isHidden` property programmatically, or set its initial value on the storyboard.

The code for that would be

##### Programmatic

```
button1.isHidden = true  // or false
```

An example for the toggling the `isHidden` property programmatically can be seen below

[image]

##### Storyboard

[image]

If all fails,

1. Check the distribution
2. If `button1.isHidden` is called